# Multiple route names for the same page in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Is it possible to have multiple route names for a page depending on how the user arrived at the page, but keeping the same RouteConfig path?

e.g.

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: 'sweet/:id',
    name: 'SweetDetailLandingPage',
    component: SweetDetailComponent,
    data: { fromLink: false, fromDeepLink: true }
  },
{
    path: 'sweet/:id',
    name: 'SweetDetailFromLink',
    component: SweetDetailComponent,
    data: { fromLink: true, fromDeepLink: false }
  }
])
```

For example, if the user enters the URL into the browser, I want the app to load `SweetDetailLandingPage`. If the user arrives at the page internally via `navigate(['SweetDetailFromLink'])`, I want to load `SweetDetailFromLink`.

The reason is because I want to determine whether the user arrived via a deep link or not and be able to call certain functions on load.

I tried this code but the app throws an error saying that there is a conflict.

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Configuration 'sweet/:id' conflicts with existing route 'sweet/:id'
```

I understand why there is a conflict. I'm just wondering if there is a way to implement what I explained above.

Comment: Can't you check this in your controller instead (how the user got to the page)?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a different approach. Read `window.location.href` either outside or (if it works inside Angular in the constructor of the root component) and if you get a deep link then redirect from there.

There is only one time during the application lifecycle whre a deep link can be loaded, this is when the application is loaded. 
Afterwards an URL change always results in a page reload. The only way to reach deep links afterwards is by the code of your Angular application (`routerLink` or `router.navigateXxx()` **except you are using `HashLocationStrategy` instead of the default `PathLocationStrategy**.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in that case is: in the routerLinks add a query string parameter `this._router.navigate(['SweetDetailLandingPage', {fromDeepLink: 'true'}]);`
and then in the load method where you want to deside to do something if you came from a deep link or not ask for that parameter:

```
if (this.getParameterByName('fromDeepLink') === 'true'){
     //do something
}else{
     //do something different
}
```